# how to prove this question of eigen-values and eigen-vectors?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

If
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta & \csc\theta & 1 \\
\sec\theta & \cos\theta & 1 \\
\tan\theta & \cot\theta & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then prove that there does not exist a real value of $\theta$ for which characteristics roots of $A$ are $-1,1,3$

i tried to solve as follows, 
sum of eigen value $$=\sin\theta +\cos\theta + 1=-1+1+3=3$$
$$\sin\theta +\cos\theta = 2$$
but what to do next.

Comment: You’re almost there. Is there any value of $\theta$ for which both the sine and cosine are equal to one?

Comment: Do you know how to find the amplitude of $\sin\theta+\cos\theta$?

Comment: i don't know how to find amplitude of $sin\theta + cos\theta$

Comment: Hint: $\cos\frac{\pi}{4} = \sin\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{eqnarray}
a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta&=&\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left[\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin\theta+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos\theta\right]\\
&=&\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left[\sin\phi\sin\theta+\cos\phi\cos\theta\right]\\
&=&\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(\theta-\phi)
\end{eqnarray}

Where $$\phi=\arcsin\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

[image: Amplitude of sinusoidal]

So the result is a sinusoidal with a phase shift and an amplitude of $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

When $a=b=1$ what will be the amplitude?

Comment: amplitude will be $\sqrt2$. but how can i prove that $\theta$ has no real value.

Comment: That is correct. So the sum $\sin\theta+\cos\theta$ can never be larger than $\sqrt{2}$ for real values of $\theta$, correct?

Comment: Therefore $\cos\theta+\sin\theta=2$ has no solution for real values of $\theta$ since $2>\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos x+\sin x=2\implies(\cos x+\sin x)^2=4\implies\cos^2+2\cos x\sin x+\sin^2x=4\\\implies\sin2x=3\ (!)$$